# How put Laravel site on shared hosting which has multiple other sites in subdirectories?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, shared-hosting

I have a Laravel site running locally on my machine, but I'd like to make it live. I already pay for shared hosting, and I have a number of sites running on the shared host in their own subdirectories. So for example, in the shared hosting, I have:

```
public_html/site1
public_html/site2
etc.
```

These are all personal sites. So I'd like to put my Laravel site on there too:

```
public_html/laravelsite
```

The issue is that I obviously don't want the majority of the files to actually be publicly accessible. If I split them up though and just put the `public` site files into `public_html/laravelsite` and put the rest of the files in a folder above public_html, nothing will be able to locate anything else and the site won't work.

Is there another work-around I can use to secure my files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When users request your site, the starting point is always `public/inde.php`. So put the public folder where you want and the rest (Laravel) where you want. Then from `public/index.php`, try to link `bootstrap/autoload.php`.

For instance, in your case you would go to `public/index.php` and change lines 22 and 36 so they can still find the `autload.php` file like this:

```
22. require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

becomes

```
22. require __DIR__.'/../../laravel_folder/bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

And

```
36. $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

becomes

```
35. $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../laravel_folder/bootstrap/app.php';
```

There are other ways of doing the same. Just find the one that suits your needs.

For Elixir, "...you may begin any file path with ./. This instructs Elixir to begin at the project root, rather than using the default base directory". Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir. So you have do something like this to change the source

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('./app/assets/sass/app.scss');
});
```

You can do the same to change the destination. 
Now if you want to minimize the differences between your dev and prod, reorganize your folder in dev to have a similar structure.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to have worked, although I'm still getting an error because I did a git clone and forgot that node_modules and vendor weren't getting saved to the repo. Once I've transferred all the files over and can confirm that it is working, I'll select this as the right answer- thank you!

Comment: I'm still getting an error: "File css/all.css not defined in asset manifest." I'm assuming it has something to do with the fact that the directory paths have changed, but I haven't been able to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: I took out the {{ elixir('css/all.css') }}, cleared the cache and put in the link directly. That seems to have resolved it.

Comment: Ok cool. Then are you going to accept this answer ? Sorry wasn't here to reply to your comment. As for the assets, nope nothing changed because everything starts from `public/index.php` as I said previously. So from `public` you can still link to your assets the same way you do on local computer.

Comment: The problem with the assets is that the path hasn't changed for Elixir, so Elixir is looking in the wrong place. I'm looking around for additional solutions so I don't have to modify the Elixir config (I'd rather modify as few things as possible in production to minimize problems when pushing from my dev box).

Comment: Thanks, but I had already tried putting absolute paths in my gulp.js file and I'm still getting the same error. I think I'm going to have to try a different approach.

Comment: To clarify, I'm not running gulp in production - the problem is not how my gulp file is set up. The problem is that when you run elixir('css/all.css'), elixir looks for the file relative to the document root, which doesn't work in my case since the site is inside a subfolder. I did some research, and this really isn't configurable unfortunately. Apparently mine is an odd use case. So I'm just doing environment detection and giving up on cache-busting in production. It's more useful in development anyway. Thanks for your help with everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening AppServiceProvider.php and modify as following:

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
            return base_path().'/public_html/laravelsite';
        });
    }
}
```

And put the contents of public folder to laravelsite folder.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I think I might go with another solution but this one looks good as well.

Answer (score 0):

Most obvious solution - just tell your server to not serve files from `/public_html/laravelsite`?

For instance if your shared hosting is using apache, create an `.htaccess` file in `/public_html/laravelsite` with

```
Deny from all
```

Then go to your laravel's `.htaccess` file in the `public` directory and add

```
Allow from all
```

Comment: Hmm, that would be simple.